# How to save video recording through edge detection on pi

Tags: python, opencv, video, raspberry-pi, edge-detection

I am currently trying to run my code on the raspberry pi using a raspberry camera. However, when I run it, the file saves, but it either does not allow me to view it on vlc or  it plays but static just appears - depending on the codec I use.

I have tried multiple codecs such as XVID, MJPG, MPEG, H264, and only MJPG allows a playback, but it plays back as static. While I am recording, I can see where the camera is detecting the edges all around the room. However, it does not show back the way it recorded. I have tried converting the .avi to .mp4 which is of no help. I uploaded the file to youtube, and it played the same way. I have also ran a different code without the edge detection which always seems to work just fine and play back perfectly everytime. I will include it down below in addition to the code for the edge detection.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
# Remember, you might need to change the XVID codec to something else (MPEG?)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('vid5.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480), False)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#the following is the code that plays back just fine without the canny.

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()

out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expected to see the video playback through the edge detection applied, but it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the OpenCV documentation (Link: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59):

The `cv2.VideoWriter`'s flag `isColor` is only supported on Windows. On other platforms, the encoder is always expecting color frames (i.e `channels == 3`). In your above code, when you are trying to apply Canny Edge Detection on RGB `frame`, it is returning a grayscale `frame` image. Hence you are not able to see the playback.

Try converting the single channel `frame` output to three channel frame before passing it into VideoWriter:

```
frame = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200)       # Single channel. Shape = (640, 480)
frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=-1) # Single channel. Shape = (640, 480, 1)
frame = np.concatenate((frame, frame, frame), axis=2) # 3 channel. Shape = (640, 480, 3)

out.write(frame)
```

Comment: As I am new to programming, I am a bit unsure as to where exactly to place your suggested code and I'm not sure what the sections you commented out mean

Comment: You need to add the above suggested code in the first part of the code sample you provided inside the while loop. For simplicity I replicated the first and last line of the code similar to yours. Also, the comments are for explaining the frame dimensions for each line of code.

Comment: As I implement your suggested code, I get the error below:

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.cols == width && img.rows == height && channels == 3) in write, file /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp, line 829
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edgesave.py", line 23, in <module>
    out.write(frame)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp:829: error: (-215) img.cols == width && img.rows == height && channels == 3 in function write

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention. Please convert your VideoWriter initialization to this line of code - `out = cv2.VideoWriter('vid5.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))`. Since you forced the flag of `isColor` to `False`, the code is making an assert check to see `channels==1`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the AVI file extension to get mine to work with the XVID codec